# Правильно ли говорить "я получаюсь прав"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли говорить *"я получаюсь прав"*? Получается, что "я прав" привычнее. Но слышал и "я получаюсь прав".

Answer (score 1):

Я, получается, прав.

"Получается" в данном случае — вводное слово.

https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/561/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F

Словарь-справочник по пунктуации
получается

получается
вводное слово и в значении сказуемого

1. Вводное слово. То же, что «выходит, следовательно, значит». Выделяется знаками препинания, обычно запятыми. Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах см. в Приложении 2. (↑Приложение 2)
   Ты – король, этот номер – твое королевство, а для меня, получается, здесь места нет. В. Славкин, Картина. И мать плачет в толпе, что ее не подпускают, что старшая родня, получается, должна тлеть где-то в стороне и используется только для взаимных болезней и праздников, так, что ли? Л. Петрушевская, Западня.
2. В значении сказуемого. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
   Получается беспорядочное, нескладное попурри из старых, но еще не допетых песен. А. Чехов, Палата № 6. Я её всю измерил, и получается по полтора метра на каждый дом. Ю. Коваль, Клеенка.

Answer (score 0):

Есть расхожие выражения

```
Я получился виноватым
```

и

```
Я оказался прав
```

Совмещая эти два получаем

```
Я получился прав
```

Но все таки, что-то тут не так.